# Prove that $f(x)=(e^{ix}-e^{iz_0})f_1(x)$ where $f_1(x)$ is also a trigonometric polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, polynomials, fourier-analysis

Let $f(x)=\sum_n c_ne^{inx}$ be a trigonometric polynomial. It then makes sense to define $f$ on $\mathbb{C}$ by allowing $x$ in this formula to be any complex number. Suppose $f(z_0)=0$ for some $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$. Prove that $$f(x)=(e^{ix}-e^{iz_0})f_1(x)$$ where $f_1(x)$ is also a trigonometric polynomial.

---

A trigonometric series is a formula expression $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_ne^{inx}$$ where $c_n\in\mathbb{C}$. If the series terminates, then we obtain a trigonometric polynomial. (To see this, recall $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$.)
Now this problem reminds me of the fundamental theorem of algebra, as well as the division algorithm (for polynomials). I'm not sure if they are applicable here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed related to ordinary polynomial division.

For large enough $N$ we can write $f(z)=\sum_{k=-N}^{N} c_ke^{ikx}$ where
the $c_k$ are constants in $\mathbb C$.
Let $g(t)=\sum_{j=0}^{2N} c_{j-N}t^j$ ; then $g$ is an ordinary polynomial
and $f(z)=e^{-iNz}g(e^{iz})$.

By hypothesis $e^{iz_0}$ is a root of $g$, so there is an ordinary polynomial
$h$ such that the factorization $g(t)=(t-e^{iz_0})h(t)$ holds. You may then take
$f_1(z)=e^{-iNz}h(e^{iz})$.